# ¿ Cómo importar a Unity un clip de Camtasia (editor de vídeo)?

Tags: c#, unity3d, camtasia

He hecho una Animación de una palabra en Camtasia (programa de edición de vídeo similar a SoniVegas) y me gustaría colocar esa animación en Unity, es posible o alguien lo ha hecho alguna vez?

Lo que he hecho es ponerlo tal cual , es decir, guardarlo y arrastrarlo a la carpeta de mi proyecto, pero me aparece un archivo raro ( no se puede ver que es un clip, no me da opciones de nada) en Unity y no sé si se puede importar de una forma determinada para que se pueda interpretar ¿ Es posible?

He buscado en documentación de Unity, Google y YouTuBe pero no he encontrado nada referido a esto, sólo a gifs (no me sirve).

Comment: Puedes checar que tipos de archivos se pueden importar a Unity y ver si puedes exportar tu archivo en Camtasia en alguno de estos formatos https://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/Manual/3D-formats.html

Comment: Vale, voy a echarle un ojo a los dos, y de acuerdo Arie, voy a echarle un poco mas de tiempo, porque llevo desde ayer por la mañana solo con esto .....

Comment: Creo que ya me funciona, gracias @ArieCwHat :) +1

Comment: como es que la borraste y la publicaste de nuevo?

Comment: @ArieCwHat por favor publica ese comentario como respuesta. Como comentario, la pregunta sigue abierta y sin respuesta.

Comment: bueno @Luiggi. Pero no tengo tiempo, asi que serà una respuesta incompleta :p

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar movies textures.

Por lo que tengo entendido que tienes que tener [Quicktime](https://support.apple.com/downloads/quicktime) instalado.

Luego puedes usar [MovieTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html) para mostrar el video en el juego.

Recuerda que hay que agregar un script que permita reproducir y pausar el video tambien.

Quizà tambien te sirva el metodo [PlayFullScreenMovie](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html).